# crear proyecto maven con dependencias dentro del jar final

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

tengo un proyecto java ejecutable el cual cree con maven y eclipse, en mi archivo `pom.xml` describo las dependencias que requiero para el proyecto y todo muy bien, desde eclipse, sin embargo este ejecutable en ambiente de producción pues no se va a ejecutar desde eclipse y al intentar ejecutarlo fuera del IDE me da errores como `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager` en clases que son de las dependencias. Al revisar el `.jar` final, las dependencias no las encuentro dentro del `jar` (En un proyecto **no maven**, estas quedan dentro del jar en el famoso folder `./lib`).

Encontre en el siguiente enlace documentación al respecto, https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven, donde el que mejor se adapta a lo que quiero hacer es con el plugin `maven-assembly-plugin`, sin embargo sigue sin copiar las dependencias al interior del jar.

Algunas cosas a saber: Mi proyecto no tiene una carpeta `./lib`, cuando creo el proyecto lo hago con el comando `mvn clean install`.

Agradezco de su colaboración en indicarme si falta configurar algo o realizar alguna otra actividad. Gracias.

**Archivo `pom.xml`**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mi_app</groupId>
<artifactId>MiAppEjecutable</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>com.mi_app.MiClaseEjecutable</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

despues de muchas pruebas moviendo para un lado u otro el archivo pom.xml, la solución fue la de quitar el tag `<pluginManagement>` que engloba al tag `<plugins>`, claro esta dejando este último como hijo del tag `<build>`

```
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      .
      .
      .
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Otra cosa importante que note, es que las dependencias deben tener el tag  declarado

```
<version>${version_dependencia}</version>
```

Esto por que tenia unas versiones sin este tag pero con el tag

```
<scope>provider</scope>
```

en este caso las dependencias no se descargaban y por ende no se empaquetaban.