# ¿Como compilar provecto de Maven con todas sus dependencias?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, scraping

He desarrollado un bot en IntelliJ que escrapea datos de una página usando Selenium, los cuales luego me envía por correo. Me gustaría exportar el proyecto para poder ejecutarlo automáticamente de forma periódica. He probado a construir el .jar del proyecto mediante los Artifact de IntelliJ, pero al ejecutarlo no ocurre nada.

Aquí está el link al repositorio de GitHub donde está el bot, por si ayuda[GitHub](https://github.com/burned301/Notificador_eventos_JOBO)
El código no contiene la contraseña de acceso a la pagina en la que inicia sesión por motivos obvius

Por favor mandad ayuda

Comment: Pablo, estas en StackOverflow en **Español** deberías editar tu pregunta y traducirla.

Comment: puedes usar la clase scheduler, esta clase te permite ejecutar tareas en forma automática, con esta clase puedes setear vía Cron Expression, cuando se debe ejecutar tu tarea, me tomaría mucho tiempo explicar con detalles como usar, pero te dejo este tutorial. [scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/quick-start-guide.html) [Cron Expression](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

Comment: Estuve en el mismo dilema, aunque no he probado la solución de Manuel de La Cruz acá dejo lo que realice https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303787/crear-proyecto-maven-con-dependencias-dentro-del-jar-final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He clonado tu proyecto, checa el código ( https://github.com/mdxmtz/Notificador_eventos_JOBO.git) .
Lo que hice fue agregar un plugin en maven para incluir el archivo exe, espero esto te ayude.

Lo puedes construir con:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Agrego los plugins agregados al pom:

```xml
 <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <finalName>crawler</finalName>
                  <archive>
                      <manifest>
                          <mainClass>Notificador_eventos_JOBO.Notificador_eventos_JOBO.App</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                      <descriptorRef>
                          jar-with-dependencies
                      </descriptorRef>                    
                  </descriptorRefs>
                  <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>


          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                      <nonFilteredFileExtension>exe</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                  </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Ahora el bot compila pero me da error.
Para que Selenium funcione, ha de acceder a un driver de un browser (en este caso he optado por GoogleChrome), y el driver no se incluye en el ejecutable que genera.

¿Existe alguna forma de incluir este driver en el ejecutable?

¡Muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: Vale nada, simplemente he metido la carpeta con el driver de Google Chrome dentro de la carpeta target, ¡ya está funcionando!

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda