# Problema con archivo JAR de programa Java con base de datos MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jar, jcalendar

¿Cómo les va? Me acabo de crear una cuenta en este foro ya que no fui capáz de encontrar solución a mi problema.
Acabo de hacer un programa para el manejo de un hotel Java en NetBeans usando una base de datos MySQL. Si ejecuto el programa desde el IDE, funciona a la perfección: no hay errores, no se lanzan excepciones, la conexión con la base de datos funciona correctamente, los datos se cargan y las tablas se visualizan bien. El problema viene a la hora de ejecutar el archivo JAR que se genera.

Al hacer doble click al JAR, el programa no abre; resulta que en el archivo MANIFEST.MF no estaba declarada la clase principal, así que lo hice manualmente y el programa logró ejecutarse. El siguiente problema fue que faltaba el directorio de la librería que usé (JCalendar):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La coloqué manualmente dentro del JAR y las ventanas que usaban la librería lograron verse correctamente. **Segundo problema:** los métodos `close()` que cerraban las conexiones de ResultSet, PreparedStatement, etc. arrojaban una NullPointerException, algo que no sucedía al ejecutar el programa en el IDE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intenté hacer fue quitar los bloques de código que invocaban al método para cerrar las conexiones. **Tercer problema:** Como estoy usando una pool de conexiones, faltaban las librerías del DBCP2 (BasicDataSource, Logging):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que también las puse manualmente. **Cuarto problema:** De este problema ya no logro salir. El siguiente es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me resulta muy raro que las dependencias y librerías no funcionen en el JAR. No se qué es lo que está pasando. A continuación les comparto el archivo pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.proyectoHotel</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProyectoHotel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.ventanas.Frame</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toedter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <index>true</index>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

Experimenté un poco usando algunas dependencias como el Compiler Plugin de Maven, pero no hubo efecto. Ahora les muestro una parte del código en donde realizo una conexión a la base de datos; en este código, por ejemplo, inserto en la tabla de "reservas" de la base de datos reservas de habitaciones del hotel:

```
package com.mycompany.conexion;

import java.sql.*;
import com.mycompany.dominio.Reserva;

public class ReservasDAO implements InterfazDAO<Reserva> {
    
    @Override
    public void insertar(Reserva r) {
        String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO reservas(habitacion, apellido_reserva, nombre_reserva, fecha) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        
        try {
            cn = Conexion.getConnection();
            stmt = cn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);
                
            stmt.setInt(1, r.getHabitacionReserva());
            stmt.setString(2, r.getApellidoReserva());
            stmt.setString(3, r.getNombreReserva());
            stmt.setDate(4, r.getFecha());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
      
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                Conexion.close(stmt);
                Conexion.close(cn);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
    }
```

El código es prácticamente el mismo para todos los "querys" de la BD.
Este es el archivo MANIFEST.MF LUEGO de escribir la clase principal manualmente:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.2.2
Build-Jdk-Spec: 18
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar protobuf-java-3.19.4.jar jca
 lendar-1.4.jar commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar maven-compiler-plugin-3.10.1.jar
  maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar commons-io-2.6.jar maven-shared-increment
 al-1.1.jar plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar plexus-java-1.1.1.jar
  asm-9.2.jar qdox-2.0.1.jar plexus-compiler-api-2.11.1.jar plexus-utils
 -3.4.1.jar plexus-compiler-manager-2.11.1.jar plexus-compiler-javac-2.1
 1.1.jar commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar commons-logging-1.2.jar
Specification-Title: ProyectoHotel
Specification-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: ProyectoHotel
Implementation-Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Main-Class: com.mycompany.ventanas.Frame
```

Para terminar, quiero aclarar que no estoy usando herramientas como Glassfish, Tomcat, Spring, o cualquier otra herramienta de aplicaciones web. Simplemente es un programa Java con base de datos en MySQL. También quisiera volver a aclarar que el programa anda perfecto cuando lo ejecuto en NetBeans.

Agradecería muchísimo su ayuda, ya que no se cómo salir de esto.

Muchas gracias.

**Edit**

Adjunto capturas del archivo JAR por dentro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de la carpeta com están los paquetes y clases del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de META-INF:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, dentro de la carpeta maven de META-INF:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit 2**

Acabo de solucionarlo agregando: `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`
al código con el que se realiza la conexión, y agregando manualmente los paquetes de com.mysql dentro del JAR. Tenía entendido que ya no era necesario utilizar Class.forName().

Sin embargo, todavía me resulta raro el hecho de que las librerías no se agreguen automáticamente al archivo luego de compilar el programa.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, y cualquier información que puedan brindar también será agradecida!

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta la estructura del jar resultante y cómo ejecutas la aplicación.

Comment: Considera que para una aplicación cliente no necesitas pool de conexiones. Cerciórate que en tu jar (descomprímelo) se encuentra el archivo `db.properties`.

Comment: El JAR lo ejectuto desde la consola de comandos con java -jar "nombre".jar: sin el pool de conexiones llegaba a los mismos resultados, y no hay archivo ```db.properties``` dentro. Ahí acabo de agregar algunas imágenes de lo que hay en el JAR.

Comment: Acabo de agregar un segundo edit con la "solución" a la que llegué. Gracias!

Comment: Para el caso de incluir las dependencias la confiugracion la puedes hallar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303787/crear-proyecto-maven-con-dependencias-dentro-del-jar-final a eso se llama fatjar

Comment: No sabía lo del fat jar. Gracias! me sirvió mucho.